# foreach not working when I using sort on an array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm using sort to sort an array alphabetically that's done like this:

```
$Consumer[] = "Norman";
$Consumer[] = "Food";
$Consumer[] = "Clothes";
$Consumer[] = "Chips";
```

But when I use this code to output the array, it won't work.

```
$cat = sort($Consumer);
foreach ($cat as $value) 
{
   echo '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</option>';
}
```

It works if I remove the sort. What am I doing wrong here and how do I set this right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### sort acts by reference

As indicated in [the docs](http://es.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) sort acts by reference and returns a boolean

> bool sort ( array &$array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_REGULAR ] )

so `$cat` is a boolean (true or false).

The following is a working example of your code:

```
$Consumer[] = "Norman";
$Consumer[] = "Food";
$Consumer[] = "Clothes";
$Consumer[] = "Chips";

sort($Consumer);
foreach ($Consumer as $value) 
{
   echo '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</option>';
}
```

Comment: Actually, `sort()` returns a boolean.

Answer (score 4):

[`sort`](http://php.net/sort) function returns boolean value so you are overwriting your data.
It modifies your `$Consumer` variable by reference.

Try with:

```
sort($Consumer);
foreach ($Consumer as $value) 
{
   echo '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</option>';
}
```